# Get Webstorm to play a sound or change icon when Grunt finishes

Tags: gruntjs, webstorm

I have about a 5-10 second grunt task that runs when I save a LESS or JS file. I'm using the Webstorm Grunt task runner to run my Gruntfile.js. Has anyone heard of a plugin for Webstorm with will notify with a sound or with a change of Grunt icon when the job is done? I'm trying to avoid keeping the Grunt console in view which takes up screen real-estate.

Comment: Not sound -- but notification balloon is possible: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11713#comment=27-718038

Comment: Hey LazyOne, exactly what I was after. Feel free to post as a solution so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [grunt-notify](https://github.com/dylang/grunt-notify) to get notifications when a task completes regardless of the OS you use.